# How can I get a nested relationship database specific columns with Eloquent ::with method?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, lumen

I have the below 3 tables:

**posts**<--(hasMany)--**users**--(hasOne)-->**user_info**

```
-------------------------------------------------
                     Post
-------------------------------------------------
id | user_id | content | created_at | updated_at
```

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                           users
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id | user_info_id | email| username | password | access_token | created_at | updated_at
```

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                      user_info
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id | user_id | name | web | birthday | gender | bio_description | profile_picture | created_at | updated_at
```

The relationships stablished as below:

**User.php**

```
...
    public function userInfo() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\UserInfo');
    }
...
    public function posts() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }
...
```

**UserInfo.php**

```
...
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
...
```

**Post.php**

```
...
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
...
```

And I get all the posts with the user and user_info nested data like this:

```
Post::with('user.userInfo')
```

which returns something like this:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "created_at": "2020-08-01 06:10:00",
            "updated_at": "2020-08-01 06:10:00",
            "user_id": 1,
            "content": "My first post!",
            "user": {
                "id": 1,
                "user_info_id": 1,
                "email": "myemail@gmail.com",
                "username": "derek",
                "access_token": "secret",
                "created_at": "2020-08-01 04:15:09",
                "updated_at": "2020-08-01 04:15:09",
                "user_info": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "user_id": 1,
                    "name": "Derek Baker",
                    "web": "https://github.com/derek90",
                    "birthday": "1990-11-27",
                    "gender": "M",
                    "bio_description": "Software Developer",
                    "profile_picture": null
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "created_at": "2020-08-01 06:09:54",
            "updated_at": "2020-08-01 06:09:54",
            "user_id": 1,
            "content": "My second post!",
            "user": {
                "id": 1,
                "user_info_id": 1,
                "email": "myemail@gmail.com",
                "username": "derek",
                "remember_token": null,
                "access_token": "secret",
                "created_at": "2020-08-01 04:15:09",
                "updated_at": "2020-08-01 04:15:09",
                "user_info": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "user_id": 1,
                    "name": "Derek Baker",
                    "web": "https://github.com/derek90",
                    "birthday": "1990-11-27",
                    "gender": "M",
                    "bio_description": "Software Developer",
                    "profile_picture": null
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

What I want, is to obtain just a few columns of each entity, like so:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "created_at": "2020-08-01 06:10:00",
            "updated_at": "2020-08-01 06:10:00",
            "content": "My first post!",
            "user": {
                "id": 1,
                "username": "derek",
                "user_info": {
                    "name": "Derek Baker",
                    "profile_picture": null
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "created_at": "2020-08-01 06:09:54",
            "updated_at": "2020-08-01 06:09:54",
            "content": "My second post!",
            "user": {
                "id": 1,
                "username": "derek",
                "user_info": {
                    "name": "Derek Baker",
                    "profile_picture": null
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this using `Post::with` Eloquent function?

I already tried with `Post::with('user:id,username', 'user.userInfo')` which works well for the user columns, but userInfo brings all of its.

Other things I've tried:

`Post::with('user:id,username', 'user.userInfo:name,profile_picture')` which brings `"user_info": null` in the json field

`Post::with('user:id,username', 'user.userInfo:userInfo.name,userInfo.profile_picture')` which show the error `Unknown column 'userInfo.name' in 'field list'`

The same error is thrown using `user.userInfo:user.userInfo.name,user.userInfo.profile_picture` and `user.userInfo:user.user_info.name,user.user_info.profile_picture`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use API Resources
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-resources#introduction

> API Resource acts as a transformation layer that sits between your
> Eloquent models and the JSON responses that are actually returned to
> your application's users.

You may create an API resource for the post and use it wherever you're returning the post in the response.

Api resources gives you a lot more control, you could manipulate whatever field you want, send some extra fields using the combination of a few fields, change the name of the fields that you want in your response (`xyz => $this->name`)

**PostResource**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class PostResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        //You can access model properties directly using $this

        return [
            "id" => $this->id,
            "created_at" => $this->created_at,
            "updated_at" => $this->updated_at,
            "content" => $this->content,
            "user" => [
                "id" => $this->user->id,
                "username" => $this->user->username,
                "user_info" => [
                    "name" => $this->user->userInfo->name,
                    "profile_picture" => $this->user->userInfo->profile_picture,
                ]
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

And then wherever you want to return a post as a response.

Controller

```
// $post is a Post Model Instance.

return new PostResource($post);
```

In case you have a collection

```
// $posts is a collection of Post Model instances.

return PostResource::collection($posts);
```

PostResource will be applied for every model instance in your collection and then returned to you as your JSON response.

[**NOTE**]

You may create similar resource for users, and any model. It makes it easier to customize the response as you like.

Also, in the above example. Instead of having user_info inside user, you could simply add the user_info properties to the user only.

```
        return [
            "id" => $this->id,
            "created_at" => $this->created_at,
            "updated_at" => $this->updated_at,
            "content" => $this->content,
            "user" => [
                "id" => $this->user->id,
                "username" => $this->user->username,
                "name" => $this->user->userInfo->name,
                "profile_picture" => $this->user->userInfo->profile_picture,
            ]
        ];
```

Comment: Interesting. Thanks. I'm trying to apply this solution but I have to figure it out how to make it work with ordering the result. (What I have is
`Post::with('user:id,username', 'user.userInfo')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(10, ['page'=>$pageNumber])`
)

Comment: Oh, don't worry, you can directly pass the paginated instance to the collection method , like this `PostResource::collection($paginated_instance)`. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-resources#pagination  `You may always pass a paginator instance to the collection method of a resource`

Comment: yeah, I did that, but it only returns the posts list. I'm missing all the other fileds that ->paginate(10) was giving me when wrapping the posts in the json data field (current_page, etc). I need this information to send to the frontend as well, to know which page to request. Should I add those fields somehow in a different API Resource?

Comment: No, you shouldn't do it separately as it should give the meta and link fields as it's mentioned in the documentation. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-resources#pagination

Comment: This is what I'm doing:
`$posts = Post::with('user:id,username', 'user.userInfo')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(10, ['page'=>$pageNumber]);`
`return response()->json(PostResource::collection($posts), 200)`

Comment: Yeah, it's strange that it's not working as expected, I was trying to search if that error has occurred before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219071/discussion-between-aashish-gaba-and-derek-baker).

Comment: For anyone having trouble with pagination and API Resources, @Aashish gaba found that I had to return `PostResource::collection($posts)` instead of `json(PostResource::collection($posts), 200)`. Now it works! Thank you very much!!!